# Paganini's Cantabile for violin and guitar in D - clarification on the notation

Tags: notation, violin, fermata

This is from Niccolò Paganini's [*Cantabile for violin and guitar in D*](https://imslp.org/wiki/Cantabile%2C_MS_109_(Paganini%2C_Niccol%C3%B2)):

[image: Passage of music for violin. A few notes with a certain symbol above them have been boxed in red. The symbol is is a semicircle with a dot in the middle.]

How do I play the red-boxed notes properly?

- What does the hat-dot signs mean? What are they called?

Comment: This is a standard notation symbol you should easily be able to find in any list of notation symbols. E.g. look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_symbols

Comment: It is hard to believe that you can be playing something this complex and not be familiar with a fermata symbol.

Comment: That sign would have been met many years before a piece this complex should be attempted. Vtc as it appears no research has been carried out to find an answer.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy I do play this piece by violin, but I am a lot self-taught.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are *fermatas*, and they indicate to hold the note longer than the given duration. There’s no defined length, but 1.5x the given duration is a frequently suggested rule of thumb. They create a musical “wait for it” moment.

Comment: Whilst this does answer the question, which is facile, it also encourages folk to ask all sorts of similar inconsequential ones, in my opinion. And surely it has to be a dupe.